# Which data structure is sensible for time series data in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I'm new to Java, so I'm not sure which choice of data structure would be good here. I'll store  accelerometer, gyroscope and magnetometer data (9 values) in a list, to be used later for smoothing, display and some signal processing.

My idea is to create an object `MyObject` that has ten members: time stamp and the nine orientation/motion values, all of them floats. I'll then store the data in an `ArrayList<MyObject>`. Is it a good idea or have I overlooked something?

The list will hold at most 100k values.

Comment: Is there the possibility of concurrent access?

Comment: @fge No, everything will run in a single thread.

Comment: Well then an ArrayList is fine. But 100k values is quite sizeable, do you write these to persistent storage before processing or do you process them while running?

Comment: @fge It will be stored on a file. Processing won't happen in real-time.

Comment: Well then you should be OK with what you have in mind ;)

Comment: Do you want to be able to query the data, e.g. "retrieve all data with timestamps between X and Y"?

Comment: In terms of OO-ness: it would be better to have classes `MyObject` (pick a better name btw), `AccelerometerData`, `GyroscopeData`, and `MagnetometerData`. Then, `MyObject` could encapsulate one of each of the classes as a field. If they are all of the same form, you could use something like a `class FloatTuple { float a, b, c; }` and `class MyObject { FloatTuple gyroscope, accelerometer, magnetometer; }`.

Comment: Keep it simple. What you suggest seems fine. If performance is not good enough you can always optimise later.

Answer (score 1):

Use TreeMap for a start to improve lookup performance.

[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)

Note (in docs):

> This implementation provides guaranteed log(n) time cost for the containsKey, get, put and remove operations.

Comment: @fge For n = 100k, n versus log(n), log(n) = 5 and n = 100 000. If I was searching for a particular item and it happened to be the last item I would have to search through 100 000 items in order to match the last item. Maybe a Hashmap of the attributes could create an index into ArrayList in order to provide 1 step array index access. Not too sure how a sorted arraylist could provide faster access if you don't know the index to item you are looking for ?

Comment: Read the comments: he _does not have to access the data_ in his program, only store it, processing is done later. As such he needs a "fast-insertion only" data structure. `TreeMap` is overkill for that.

Comment: Writes to an ArrayList are O(1). And, since the data is sorted  searches are O(log(n)).

Comment: How can inserts into ArrayList be O(1) when you have to sort the data first ?

Comment: @Excalibur2000 The data is obtained in order since I'm logging sensor data.

Comment: @axblount since `ArrayList` is not sorted, it will not do binary searchs (the items **may be** ordered, but `ArrayList` cannot count on it for its logic)

Comment: @SJuan76 That is true in the general case but, per Andreas' comment, this is time series data being inserted in order.

Comment: if i have duplicated time stamps in my case. What should i use?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using a file output stream to output your data directly, rather than storing it in some data structure:

```
output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("output.csv"));

while(dataSource.stillHasData())
    output.println(dataSource.getData().toString());

output.close();
```

Using a `BufferedWriter` ensures that the program doesn't have to wait for disk writes to happen before it can take the next data, so this would be acceptable for collecting live data (usually).

You should then do something like this in your data class:

```
public String toString(){
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    buf.append(timeStamp); str.append(',');
    // ...
    // append all the other data

    return buf.toString();
}
```

This way of doing it has advantage that you can then import it into programs like excel or really just about any program that you would use to process the data.

Answer (score 0):

Creating your own class is the right way to go. Now for storing the objects of that class...

If you need direct lookup (e.g., "give me the 5th object") on the objects once you have all of them, use an `ArrayList`.  But if you will just be looping over all of the objects in order, you should consider using a [linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

The `ArrayList` class uses a primitive array that it will grow as needed to accommodate the elements you are adding to it.  When it grows its internal structure, it needs to allocate a new array and copy over all of the original values.  This can be costly (especially with 100K elements!).  You *can* give it an initial size to give it more time before it needs to grow; but if you end up not needing so much space, the ArrayList's internal array can waste a large chunk of memory.

Adding elements to a linked list costs virtually nothing because "growing" is not needed; it just adds another node to the list.  But you can't look up items by their index. You would have to start at the first element and loop through the list to the element you want.